# Linux csh , copy text from utf-8 file to other file result gibberish

Tags: utf-8, csh, iconv

i have utf-8 with Russian characters i try to copy from to new file
but the result is gibberish characters .
the source file can be open and seen good in vim . 
this is part of my script ,

```
# this is how i found in the internet to convert file to utf-8
set new_file_full_path = "/home/foo/env/output/test.csv"
set f = "/home/foo/env/source/source_test.txt"
if( ! -e $new_file_full_path ) then
         touch  $new_file_full_path
       iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 $new_file_full_path
endif
set new_line_buffer = ""
foreach line("`cat $source_dir/$f`")
#echo $line
if( $i > 14 ) then
   echo "about to append to file"
   echo $new_file_full_path
   echo $line >> $new_file_full_path
   echo "done append to file"
 endif
 @ i = $i + 1
 end
```

i think part of the problem is when i do :

the destination file

```
file -i /home/foo/env/output/test.csv
/home/foo/env/output/test.csv: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit terminators
```

and the source file

```
file -i /home/foo/env/source/source_test.txt
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

as you see the destination file is not utf-8 file even after i try to convert it

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need `iconv` if you want to keep UTF-8 in your source and destination file.

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 $new_file_full_path
```

Here You are asking a conversion **from** latin1 **to** UTF-8 of the file `/home/foo/env/output/test.csv`, the result shall appear in `stdout` as you didn't specify an output file.

I think that you want something like:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 $f -o $new_file_full_path
```

With `$f` your source file in UTF-8, and get the conversion in `$new_file_full_path`, in latin1, if it is what you want.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realized: [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is probably not the encoding you want for your destination file: it does not support Russian characters. You might want to try [ISO_8859-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5) instead.
BTW I'm not sure about what you are doing after the `endif`...